# Routing Error - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes

I am getting the following error on my app when I try to access /messages/new:

```
No route matches [GET] "/messages/new"
```

If I try adding a /messages/new route to config.rb, I get the following error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"messages"}
```

The app itself is like Gumtree.com, where Users come and create Posts (e.g. selling my car), and people respond my sending them Messages (through the Simple Pvt Messages plugin).

Any insights on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Faisal

**ROUTES.RB**

```
Mysalary::Application.routes.draw do
resources :users do
         resources :messages do
           collection do
             post :delete_selected
           end
         end
       end

resources :users
resources :profiles
resources :pages
resources :posts
resources :messages

get "pages/home"
get "pages/about"
get "pages/legal"
get "pages/feedback"

root :to => 'posts#new'

end
```

**MESSAGE>NEW VIEW**

```
<% form_for @message, :url => user_messages_path(@user) do |f| %>
<p>
To:<br />
    <%= f.text_field :to %>
    <%= error_message_on @message, :to %>
</p>
<p>
Subject:<br />
<%= f.text_field :subject %>
<%= error_message_on @message, :subject %>
</p>
<p>
  Message<br />
  <%= f.text_area :body %>
        <%= error_message_on @message, :body %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= submit_tag "Send" %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

**MESSAGES CONTROLLER**

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

before_filter :set_user

def index
if params[:mailbox] == "sent"
  @messages = @user.sent_messages
else
  @messages = @user.received_messages
end
end

def show
@message = Message.read_message(params[:id], current_user)
end

def new
@message = Message.new

if params[:reply_to]
  @reply_to = @user.received_messages.find(params[:reply_to])
  unless @reply_to.nil?
    @message.to = @reply_to.sender.login
    @message.subject = "Re: #{@reply_to.subject}"
    @message.body = "\n\n*Original message*\n\n #{@reply_to.body}"
  end
end
end

def create
@message = Message.new(params[:message])
@message.sender = @user
@message.recipient = User.find_by_login(params[:message][:to])

if @message.save
  flash[:notice] = "Message sent"
  redirect_to user_messages_path(@user)
else
  render :action => :new
end
end

def delete_selected
if request.post?
  if params[:delete]
    params[:delete].each { |id|
      @message = Message.find(:first, :conditions => ["messages.id = ? AND (sender_id = ? OR recipient_id = ?)", id, @user, @user])
      @message.mark_deleted(@user) unless @message.nil?
    }
    flash[:notice] = "Messages deleted"
  end
  redirect_to :back
end
end

private
def set_user
 @user = User.first
end
end
```

**MESSAGE MODEL**

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

is_private_message

attr_accessor :to

end
```

**RAKE ROUTES OUTPUT**

```
            delete_selected_user_messages POST   /users/:user_id/messages/delete_selected(.:format) {:action=>"delete_selected", :controller=>"messages"}
            user_messages GET    /users/:user_id/messages(.:format)                 {:action=>"index", :controller=>"messages"}
                          POST   /users/:user_id/messages(.:format)                 {:action=>"create", :controller=>"messages"}
         new_user_message GET    /users/:user_id/messages/new(.:format)             {:action=>"new", :controller=>"messages"}
        edit_user_message GET    /users/:user_id/messages/:id/edit(.:format)        {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"messages"}
             user_message GET    /users/:user_id/messages/:id(.:format)             {:action=>"show", :controller=>"messages"}
                          PUT    /users/:user_id/messages/:id(.:format)             {:action=>"update", :controller=>"messages"}
                          DELETE /users/:user_id/messages/:id(.:format)             {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"messages"}
                 messages GET    /messages(.:format)                                {:action=>"index", :controller=>"messages"}
                          POST   /messages(.:format)                                {:action=>"create", :controller=>"messages"}
              new_message GET    /messages/new(.:format)                            {:action=>"new", :controller=>"messages"}
             edit_message GET    /messages/:id/edit(.:format)                       {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"messages"}
                  message GET    /messages/:id(.:format)                            {:action=>"show", :controller=>"messages"}
                          PUT    /messages/:id(.:format)                            {:action=>"update", :controller=>"messages"}
                          DELETE /messages/:id(.:format)                            {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"messages"}
               pages_home GET    /pages/home(.:format)                              {:action=>"home", :controller=>"pages"}
              pages_about GET    /pages/about(.:format)                             {:action=>"about", :controller=>"pages"}
              pages_legal GET    /pages/legal(.:format)                             {:action=>"legal", :controller=>"pages"}
           pages_feedback GET    /pages/feedback(.:format)                          {:action=>"feedback", :controller=>"pages"}
             messages_new GET    /messages/new(.:format)                            {:action=>"new", :controller=>"messages"}
                     root
```

Comment: how come you nest messages in user?

Comment: What is the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: Why do you resource `users` twice on the top level?

Comment: @JosephLeBrech that's the default setting that was generated through scaffold...

Comment: @klump please see rake routes output attached above..

Comment: @klaffenboeck that's the default setting generated through scaffold...should i change it? if so what change should i make..

Comment: You are defining the same thing 2 times - I think you can savly remove the second `resources :users`. Do you need to access the messages indepentent from a user? If not you should also remove the second `resources ':messages`. You could create a new message for a user via "new_user_message" (`/user/:user_id/messages/new`)

Comment: @klump, I still get this error No route matches {:controller=>"messages"}

Comment: @klump so are you saying that i should get rid of /messages/new & replace it with something like /user/:user_id/messages/new?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your route file with this you are defining resource message inside users and also twice.

Mysalary::Application.routes.draw do

```
     resources :messages do
       collection do
         post :delete_selected
       end
     end


       resources :users
       resources :profiles
       resources :pages
       resources :posts

        get "pages/home"
        get "pages/about"
         get "pages/legal"
        get "pages/feedback"

        root :to => 'posts#new'

        end
```

Try it...